# mvn clean install throws Compilation failure but same is working fine with Run as Junit

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-jvm

I set up new Cucumber-Maven project.

when i run my Runner.java file with option Run as Junit, same is working fine.
But when i try to run the same via command prompt using command "mvn clean install" then it throws error:-

```
C:\Users\HT1\workspace\com.pvrcucumber>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for PVR_CUCUMBER:com.pvrcucumber:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/sqljdbc4.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 69, column 16
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 108, column 17
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building com.pvrcucumber 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ com.pvrcucumber ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\HT1\workspace\com.pvrcucumber\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ com.pvrcucumber ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 16 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ com.pvrcucumber ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 24 source files to C:\Users\HT1\workspace\com.pvrcucumber\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[5,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[10,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[11,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[19,76] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class FindFailed
  location: class stepdefinitions.Cinemas
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/DealsExclusives.java:[7,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/DealsExclusives.java:[36,91] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class FindFailed
  location: class stepdefinitions.DealsExclusives
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[14,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[15,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[16,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[66,76] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class FindFailed
  location: class pageObject.DealsExclusivesPage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[21,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Screen
  location: class stepdefinitions.Cinemas
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[21,35] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Screen
  location: class stepdefinitions.Cinemas
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[22,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Pattern
  location: class stepdefinitions.Cinemas
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[22,34] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Pattern
  location: class stepdefinitions.Cinemas
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[94,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Screen
  location: class pageObject.DealsExclusivesPage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[94,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Screen
  location: class pageObject.DealsExclusivesPage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[95,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Pattern
  location: class pageObject.DealsExclusivesPage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[95,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Pattern
  location: class pageObject.DealsExclusivesPage
[INFO] 18 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.447 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-23T13:59:43+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project com.pvrcucumber: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[5,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[10,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[11,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[19,76] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FindFailed
[ERROR] location: class stepdefinitions.Cinemas
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/DealsExclusives.java:[7,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/DealsExclusives.java:[36,91] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FindFailed
[ERROR] location: class stepdefinitions.DealsExclusives
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[14,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[15,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[16,25] package org.sikuli.script does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[66,76] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FindFailed
[ERROR] location: class pageObject.DealsExclusivesPage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[21,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Screen
[ERROR] location: class stepdefinitions.Cinemas
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[21,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Screen
[ERROR] location: class stepdefinitions.Cinemas
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[22,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Pattern
[ERROR] location: class stepdefinitions.Cinemas
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/stepdefinitions/Cinemas.java:[22,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Pattern
[ERROR] location: class stepdefinitions.Cinemas
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[94,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Screen
[ERROR] location: class pageObject.DealsExclusivesPage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[94,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Screen
[ERROR] location: class pageObject.DealsExclusivesPage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[95,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Pattern
[ERROR] location: class pageObject.DealsExclusivesPage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/HT1/workspace/com.pvrcucumber/src/main/java/pageObject/DealsExclusivesPage.java:[95,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Pattern
[ERROR] location: class pageObject.DealsExclusivesPage
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

and my pom.xml is:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>PVR_CUCUMBER</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.pvrcucumber</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>com.pvrcucumber</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
   <version>4.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>



    </dependencies>


     <build>
  <plugins>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

</plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When i run my runner.java class via Runas->junit it works fine but with mvn clean install it's not.

pls suggest!!

Comment: What is your package structure? Is the source code under src/main/java?

Comment: src/main/java- contains code and stepdefinitions.   src/test/java-contains my runner class and src/main/resources-contains features file

Comment: Your package in not on classpath...not sure why unless I see the code

Answer (score 1):

When you run a mvn clean install, everything that is required to compile your project must be defined in the dependencies section of your pom file.
When you run a junit, everything that is required to compile your project must be defined in the classpath.

In this case, the package org.sikuli.script can be found on the classpath of your junit but cannot be found in your maven dependencies.

To fix this, you must add a maven dependency to your pom file which includes the maven artifact (usually a jar file) which contains the missing package.

Once you have found the jar which contains the missing package (try looking in the classpath of the runner for your junit) you can add the jar to your local maven repository to create the artifact and then include it in your pom file.
Try searching for 'How to add jar to local maven repo' for the syntax on how this is done.

Comment: Hi Suresh, I'm glad the solution works. Will you please mark my answer as 'Accepted'? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: @Before building your component (using mvn clean install). Build the entire project once and build your component again

WHY SO :
I get this error many times. Most of the times I will try to build my component alone (As I have not made changes elsewhere).

Right, But that extra jar which has been downloaded recently might have affected by changes done by a third party(inside their component). Making a full mvn clean install on entire project saved me many times

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project -> maven -> update project
It will recompile with maven and will resolve compilation issues after maven goals execution